# Parent reads operations from file and the child sums it with bc

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup2

I'm trying to make a program where the parent reads from a file some operations, passes them to the child with a pipe, and the child makes all the operations with bc. Later on, the child has to pass it back to the parent and this one has to write it on a file.

However, when I execute it, I don't get any result and don't know where the problem is. The child seems to receive the operation correctly, but with 'EXT' character.

My code works perfectly when the parent doesn't read from the file, the problem is when I try to read from a file.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EOL '\n'

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int tube1[2];
    int tube2[2];
    int fID;
    pipe(tube1);
    pipe(tube2);

    if(argc != 2){
        perror("./yourProgram.c [origin]");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fork() == 0){
        //Child Process

        close(tube1[1]); // writing end of the pipe
        dup2(tube1[0], 0);  // stdin ----> pipe reading end

        close(tube2[0]); // reading end of the pipe
        dup2(tube2[1], 1);  // stdout ---> pipe writing end

        //Execute and write the output in the tube2
        execlp("bc", "bc", "-q", NULL);
    }else {
        //Parent Process

        close(tube1[0]); // reading end of the pipe
        //dup2(tube1[1], 1); // stdout ---> pipe writing end

        close(tube2[1]); // reading end of the pipe
        //dup2(tube1[1], 1); // stdout ---> pipe writing end

     //Files
        //Destiny
        char *destiny = "final.txt";
        int destinyFile = open(destiny, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);

        //Origin
        char *origin = argv[1];
        int originFile = open(origin, O_RDONLY);

        //Variables
        char block;
        char result;
        char buffer[4096];
        int i = 0;
        int numbytes;

        while(numbytes = read(originFile, &block, sizeof(block)) > 0){
            if(block == EOL){

                //Write on the tube, so the child can read it
                if(write(tube1[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)) == -1){
                    perror("error en write en pipe");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                //Read the child's answer
                while(numbytes = read(tube2[0], &result, 1) > 0){
                    if(result != EOL){
                        //Concatenate strings as: 'X + Y = Result \n'
                        char str[80];
                        strcat(str, buffer);
                        strcat(str, " = ");
                        strcat(str, &result);
                        strcat(str, "\n");

                        //Write the result in the Final File
                        if(write(destinyFile, str, strlen(str)) == -1){
                            perror("error en write en stdout");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                    }else
                        continue;        
                }

                //Reset Buffer
                buffer[0] = '\0';
                i = 0;
             }else{
                buffer[i] = block;
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the file from where I read is:

```
2+3
4*5
8/2
quit
```

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child.  **Rule of thumb:** If you dup one end of a pipe to standard input or output, close _both_ ends of the pipe as soon as possible.  That means before using `exec*()` in particular.  Also, the `exec*()` functions return only on error, but you need to make sure that if they do return, they do no damage.  Report an error and exit.  Your code doesn't cover the case of 'failure to `fork()` — not a common problem, but a possible problem.  It's best to cover that case.

Comment: Using `read()` to read single bytes is feasible, but hardly efficient.  Unless there are constraints on you because of the exercise rules, use `getline()` or `fgets()` to read lines of data and send them to the child process.  Note that you don't null terminate the string before measuring its length — someone's going to be unhappy, sooner or later.  You don't null terminate `str` before you use `strcat()` to append to it.  This too does not lead to happiness.  Your buffer is 4096 characters long; you copy it into an 80 character space.  There's rather a lot of possibility for buffer overflow!

Answer (score 1):

This code fixes the critical problems noted in the comments (but not the performance issues from reading one byte at a time).  If the calculation produces a result that's big enough, `bc` splits its output over multiple lines (calculating factorial 100, for example).  The code does not attempt to deal with that.  Also, some operations produce no output.  For example, `c=2345` produces no output.  The program does not handle this, either.

You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child.
**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both ends
of the pipe as soon as possible.
That means before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions in particular.

The rule of thumb also includes using
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EOL '\n'

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tube1[2];   // Parent -> child
    int tube2[2];   // Child -> parent

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        perror("./yourProgram.c origin");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pipe(tube1);
    pipe(tube2);

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        // Child Process

        dup2(tube1[0], 0);  // stdin ----> pipe reading end
        close(tube1[0]);    // reading end of the pipe to child
        close(tube1[1]);    // writing end of the pipe to child

        dup2(tube2[1], 1);  // stdout ---> pipe writing end
        close(tube2[0]);    // reading end of the pipe to parent
        close(tube2[1]);    // writing end of the pipe to parent

        // Execute and write the output in the tube2
        execlp("bc", "bc", "-q", NULL);
        perror("bc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        // Parent Process
        close(tube1[0]); // reading end of the pipe to child
        close(tube2[1]); // writing end of the pipe to parent

        // Files
        // Destiny
        char *destiny = "final.txt";
        int destinyFile = open(destiny, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
        if (destinyFile < 0)
        {
            perror(destiny);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Origin
        char *origin = argv[1];
        int originFile = open(origin, O_RDONLY);
        if (originFile < 0)
        {
            perror(origin);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Variables
        char block;
        char result;
        char buffer[256];
        int i = 0;
        int numbytes;

        while ((numbytes = read(originFile, &block, sizeof(block))) > 0)
        {
            buffer[i++] = block;
            //printf("Block: [%.*s]\n", i, buffer);
            if (block == EOL)
            {
                // Write on the tube, so the child can read it
                if (write(tube1[1], buffer, i) == -1)
                {
                    perror("error en write en pipe");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                buffer[i-1] = '\0';

                // Read the child's answer
                int j = 0;
                char reply[256];
                while ((numbytes = read(tube2[0], &result, sizeof(result))) > 0)
                {
                    reply[j++] = result;
                    //printf("Reply: [%.*s]\n", j, reply);
                    if (result == EOL)
                    {
                        // Concatenate strings as: 'X + Y = Result \n'
                        char str[256];
                        str[0] = '\0';
                        strcat(str, buffer);
                        strcat(str, " = ");
                        strcat(str, reply);

                        // Write the result in the Final File
                        if (write(destinyFile, str, strlen(str)) == -1)
                        {
                            perror("error en write en stdout");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        printf("Response: [%.*s]\n", j-1, reply);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Reset Buffer
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        close(tube1[1]);
        close(tube2[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given the sample input file:

```
2+3
4*5
8/2
quit
```

the output on the screen is:

```
Response: [5]
Response: [20]
Response: [4]
```

and the output in `final.txt` is:

```
2+3 = 5
4*5 = 20
8/2 = 4
```